# Define a relation first_last(L1, L2) which takes a list L1 and returns a list L2 containing the first three and last three elements of L1

Tags: prolog

Basically I planned on getting the first three elements and also the last three and then concatenate them together. This has been a hassle. I know something like this `first([A, B, C|_])` can help me get the first three. apart from this I am completely stuck. I am a noob at prolog, please help.
Given a relation `first_last(L1, L2)`,
when I write something like `first_last([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], L2)` . where L2 is the resulting list, i should get L2 = [1,2,3,7,8,9]

Comment: What about `first_last([1,2], L)`?

Comment: well i guess it should return L = [1,2]

Comment: or `L = [1,2,1,2]` or `false`

Comment: i think false would be more appropriate since its not up to six elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
first_last(Xs, [A,B,C,X,Y,Z]) :-
   phrase(( [A,B,C], ..., [X,Y,Z] ), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Comment: DCG kata! (6 more to go...)

Comment: TIL: kata isn't cata/κατά